# mathjax, local macros not rendering in IE9 until reload

Tags: mathjax

When I first load my page in IE9 the locally defined macros are not rendered (they are displayed in red as \bepsilon for example).  When I reload the page, the math is rendered. I don't have to reload in Firefox. Here is my html and configuration:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=Accessible-full"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mathjax_config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="mediaobject">$\displaystyle = \bX \bbeta + \bepsilon  $</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My configuration has this:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
displayAlign: "left",
displayIndent:"3em",
tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
  processEscapes: true,
  skipTags: ["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre","code"]
  },
TeX: {
  Macros: {
    bDelta: '\\boldsymbol{\\Delta}',
    bepsilon: '\\boldsymbol{\\epsilon}',
    bzeta:  '\\boldsymbol{\\zeta}'
  }
}
});
```

What can I do to make IE9 load on the first hit? Does the configuration need to be in a certain order to work?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is coming too late, as MathJax will have already completed its configuration by the time your script runs.  You need to either use in-line configuration, or add your configuration file to the `config=...` list in the script that loads MathJax.  See the [MathJax Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-a-local-configuration-file-with-the-cdn) for loading a configuration file while using the CDN for details.  Be sure to pay particular attention to the information about the `loadComplete()` call.